# Html Image source from scaled down of original image

Tags: javascript, html, image, size, image-resizing

I'm looking for a way to hide the original image source. For proper example let's think of user profile picture. I don't want anyone to access original high resolution user profile picture. Currently i use  but if someone goes to inspect they can access full size profile picture of them. How can i prevent it ?

I thought about that; in register when user upload their profile picture, first it scales down and saved to the related directory. And when using i will call it like  But not sure if this is the right approach to the case.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that is impossible with HTML, CSS or JS. Because if Chrome can view the source, so can the user.

Maybe there's a way of doing this with e.g. PHP. But if you would take a look at other social medias you will find that every image or video can be found through the source.